# Turn AKMicrophone work on both headphones channels

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm faced with simple problem, on which not trivial to find an answer in google (at least for me). Working with `AudioKit 4.4`, I'm trying to make a microphone, output from which I can hear in both channels of my stereo headphones. I'm trying to set audioformat to `AudioKit.format` and `AKSettings.channelCount` manually, but in headphones I hear microphone only in left channel. What I'm missing?

Here simplified code with my current settings:

```
    AKSettings.bufferLength = .long
    AKSettings.fixTruncatedRecordings = true
    AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true
    AKSettings.ioBufferDuration = 0.002
    AKSettings.channelCount = 2
    AKSettings.enableRouteChangeHandling = false
    let format = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: 44100, channels: 2)
    AudioKit.format = format ?? AudioKit.format

    let mic = AKMicrophone()
    AudioKit.output = mic
    try? AudioKit.start()
```

As you can see, I'm just initialising `AKSettings` properties for audio session and create a microphone, that connects to `AudioKit` engine output. I suspect that `AKSettings` before `AKSettings.channelCount = 2` doesn't play any role in this problem. But I don't understand at all, what I'm doing wrong? I'm sure, it would be a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have found the answer - it is class `AKStereoFieldLimiter`:

```
let mic = AKMicrophone()
let monoToStereo = AKStereoFieldLimiter(mic, amount: 1)
let micMixer = AKMixer(monoToStereo)
AudioKit.output = micMixer
```

Also, there may be a more simple solution in `AudioKit 4.7.1` - initialisation `AKMicrophone(with format: AVAudioFormat?)`, but I can't check it, because I'm working with `AudioKit 4.4`. If someone can try this method, please, leave a feedback in comment to this answer.